# Does elixir makes a copy of a map when passed as an function argument?

Tags: elixir

In other words , I'm wondering whether in elixir a map is passed to a function by value or by reference. I suspect it is by value given Elixir's principle of no side effect. But then wouldn't a large map create huge duplication inefficiency?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since all terms in Elixir are immutable, there's no difference to the user whether the argument is passed "by value" or "by reference". You can never modify the value of a term in a function and have that reflected in the variable the caller sent to the function. Maps specifically could be considered to be passed "by reference", in that only a pointer to them is sent to the function by the VM, which is very efficient.

One thing to note is that terms passed to other processes *are* deep copied by the VM. The only exception to this is "large" Strings, usually > 64 bytes, which are passed as a reference to a global binary heap, and use reference counting for garbage collection.

> I suspect it is by value given Elixir's principle of no side effect.

Elixir is not pure, it has side effects. For example, you can add I/O to any function. You probably meant no mutable values.

Comment: I'd suggest replacing "terms passed to other processs" as "terms sent as messages"

Comment: @FredtheMagicWonderDog I thought about that, but isn't the following technically not a "message" but will deep copy the map? `map = %{...}; spawn(fn -> IO.inspect(map) end)`?

Comment: Good question. I'll have to think about that one.