# How does Elixir/Erlang manage the memory of variabes passed in function calls?

Tags: memory-management, erlang, elixir

How does the memory management of variables work in Elixir and Erlang?

Is it pass-by-reference? Pass-by-value? Something else?

Comment: An answer to this question might be found in literally each and every tutorial.

Comment: Because there is no way to observe whether a function changes a variable, no one knows.  As for memory management, erlang uses garbage collection.

Comment: See e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39996506/3457068).

Comment: Here's another answer: https://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2013-March/072760.html

Comment: More details here: https://hamidreza-s.github.io/erlang%20garbage%20collection%20memory%20layout%20soft%20realtime/2015/08/24/erlang-garbage-collection-details-and-why-it-matters.html

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)'s an equivalent Java question that has over 7000 upvotes and 2 million views. I think this question is on-topic and the down and close votes are unwarranted.

Answer (score 2):

Elixir always passes COPIES of the variable's value; Elixir never passes variables by reference. Passing by reference is impossible in Elixir even if you wanted to (unless I'm woefully mistaken).  This strategy is partly what makes Elixir particularly well suited for dealing with issues of concurrency.

Comment: I assume one should make a difference between the concept and the implementation. Conceptually, Elixir always passes values. But I assume there are several optimisations to avoid the physical copy when possible (for instance when the compiler knows that the function won't modify the variable).

Comment: Yes, for data structures it will typically only make physical copies when crossing the process boundary, as explained in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39996344/does-elixir-makes-a-copy-of-a-map-when-passed-as-an-function-argument/39996506#39996506) in a comment above.

Comment: You can see it with the following:
`list = [1, 2, 3];`
`fun = & &1;`
`fun2 = &(Task.async(fn -> &1 end) |> Task.await());`
`true = :erts_debug.same(list, fun.(list));`
`false = :erts_debug.same(list, fun2.(list))`